# preg_match url pattern

Tags: php, javascript, preg-match, file-get-contents

as I cant find exact answer to my question I decided to ask for help posting my question here. So, I have a page content which I get with `file_get_contents` and want to `preg_match` this url:

```
http://sample.com/Last/LastSearch.ashx?q=cnt=1&day=5&keyword=sample&location=15&view=v
```

from

```
<a href="javascript:LastURL('http://sample.com/Last/LastSearch.ashx?q=cnt=1&day=5&keyword=sample&location=15&view=v');" id="Last" rel="nofollow" class="Last" onclick="javascript:hideCss('LastCSS');hideCss('FirstRCSS');">Last</a>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use the DOM? That's what it's for...

If you insist on a regex, try (in PHP)

```
if (preg_match('/<a href="javascript:LastURL\(\'([^\'])*\'/', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

or (in JavaScript)

```
var myregexp = /<a href="javascript:LastURL\('([^'])*'/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
} else {
    result = "";
}
```

Comment: **Got it:** `preg_match('/<a href="javascript:LastURL\(\'(.*?)\'\)/i', $url, $match);` Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the url is always going to start with http:// then you could use the following expression within your preg_match:

```
(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)
```

Comment: `(f|ht){1}` == `(f|ht)`. `{1}` is implied.

Comment: and how to use this in my situation?